# 2k x 8 ram. Very stuck

Tags: byte, cpu-word, ram

I'm struggling with a coursework question. I'm stuck. My brain's hurting and I'm going around in circles.

The question is.

> (a)   Suppose a memory with 4-byte words and a capacity of 2^21-bit is
>   built using 2k x 8 RAM.
>
> i.    How many chips are needed?

My answer / idea here can't be correct.

Found a question that says how many chips to make 32k memory from 2k x 8 RAM? The answer is 16 chips. That makes sense 2 x 16 = 32

However, 2^21 bits?

4-byte words = 32 bits. This must be the number of bits per cell. The width of the memory?

If the entire memory holds 2^21 bits then does that mean that there will be 2^21 / 32  rows? = 65536 rows. I got to this through the thinking that I need 2^21 bits altogether. If there are 32 per row, I need 65536 rows to get to 2^21 (=2097152).

Even though I have got this far, I can't see how it helps me.

How many bits are stored on each 2k x 8 RAM?

> ii.   How many address lines are needed for the memory?

I have read that

> > "2k x 8 RAM is referred to as 2k x n memory. There are k address lines and therefore 2k addresses. Each of these addresses contains an n-bit word. 
> >     In this instance, 2k = 2048 = 211. You need 11 address lines."

I don't `100% understand the quote. I know that 2 address lines give four addresses. I know 3 address lines give 8 addresses. Do I need to work this out for 65536 rows?

> iii.  How many of these address lines are connected to the address inputs of the RAM chips?

????

> iv.   How many of these address lines will be used to select the appropriate RAM chip(s)?

I understand that some address lines are needed to select the chip whilst others are necessary for the cell in the chip. When I know the number of chips, can I work this out?

Many, many thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: You should pay attention to formatting guidelines specific for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (a) Suppose a memory with 4-byte words and a capacity of 2^21-bit is built using 2k x 8 RAM.

"8 Ram" implies this RAM chip stores bytes, and thus this chip has the capacity to store 2kB, or 512 words == 2^9 words.

Now, to store 2²¹ bits == 2^18 bytes == 2^16 words == 2^7 chips worth of words == 128 chips.

That wasn't so hard, was it?

> How many bits are stored on each 2k x 8 RAM?

2k * 8, exactly as your quoted book says.

> ii. How many address lines are needed for the memory?

Well, you need 7 lines to select the chip, and 9 lines to select the word inside the chip. 7+9 = 16.

> iii. How many of these address lines are connected to the address inputs of the RAM chips?

9, see ii.

> iv.

7, see ii.

Comment: Thank you very much Marcus. Really, it made my morning to see your help. how did you get the answer, "Well, you need 9 lines to select the word inside the chip."

I understand the 7 lines for selecting the chip with addresses from 0000000 - 1111111

Thanks again

Comment: That's why I converted the chip size to number of words contained -- 2^9, which means you need 9 lines.